# Slide out panel from within a page

Tags: tabs, slide

I'm having trouble applying the various slide panel plugins to a div within a page. So, not from the top, side or bottom of the browser window, but from somewhere within the page.

This would work...

```
$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
```

but the div slides out of view, so there's no tab to click on to slide it back up.

I could use a separate element to initiate the click function, but I need the clickable element to act as a tab connected to the sliding div.

So when the page loads, you'd see a panel in the middle of the screen, which would have a small tab sticking out of the bottom of that panel. When the tab is clicked, it slides up along with a panel with additional information. When the tab is clicked again, it slides back down.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add in another div right next to it to use as a toggling tab, one that won't be hidden. Have that tab hide/show the div you want hidden.

```
$("#tab").click(function () {
    $("#slider").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jxbkj/

Comment: Very Close. And this might work for some scenarios. What I want though is for the tab to move with the panel. With what you've provided, the panel slides down from where the tab is. 

I would like the panel and tab to slide up instead.

EDIT - I should have looked at the jsfiddle example first. That is very close to what I want, and the tab does move with the panel. I'll work with it a bit more, but I think you've provided the right solution.

Comment: Well, seems like it should be simple, but...

I want exactly the reverse of what you've provided. I want the tab on top rather than bottom, and I want the sliding to reveal up rather than down.

Comment: I've unchecked the above as answered. I was able to flip the panel and have the slide move correctly, but the tab stays where it is - so its doesn't act as though its connected to the panel.